# Python Pandas - Returning Data based on specified conditions and prevent true false values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe that's somewhat providing the output i want.  Below is the code and output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'B': [5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df['A'] > 4, df['A']
df2 = df['B'] <13, df['B']
df3 = df1 + df2
print(df3)
```

Output

```
>>> print(df3)
(0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: A, dtype: bool, 0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
Name: A, dtype: int64, 0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: B, dtype: bool, 0     5
1     8
2     9
3    10
4    11
5    12
6    13
7    14
Name: B, dtype: int64)
```

My question is, how do I prevent the output from printing the true false values as i'm just interested in the dataframes with the values

```
Desired output
 1    2
    2    3
    3    4
    4    5
    5    6
    6    7
    7    8

1     8
    2     9
    3    10
    4    11
    5    12
    6    13
    7    14
```

The desired output is two separate dataframes of just the values without the true/false outputs

Comment: What is the output you’re looking for, exactly?

Comment: It looks like there may be a typo in the line `df1 = df[['A'] > 4, df['A']]`. This may have been caused when copying the code to SO. If so, can you please correct it?

Comment: Running your first block of code produces errors, please fix it.

Comment: I've corrected the error in my question

Comment: Your expected output is still a bit unclear. What are you trying do with the original DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'A': [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,5,6,7,8], 'B': [5,0.2,4,8,11,9,10,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df[df.A >= 0.4]
print(df1) 

#    A     B
#4  5.0  11.0
#5  6.0   9.0
#6  7.0  10.0
#7  8.0  14.0

df2 = df[df.A < 0.4]
print(df2) 


#     A    B
#0  0.1  5.0
#1  0.2  0.2
#2  0.1  4.0
#3  0.2  8.0

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df3) 

#    A     B
#4  5.0  11.0
#5  6.0   9.0
#6  7.0  10.0
#7  8.0  14.0
#0  0.1   5.0
#1  0.2   0.2
#2  0.1   4.0
#3  0.2   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  the below provides me with the expected output

```
data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'B': [5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df.A > 4]
df2 = df[df.A <13]
```

Comment: I recommend using `df['A']` instead of `df.A` to access columns.

Comment: I had done that initially and it wasn't giving me the desired output. You comment isn't helpful.  Can you suggest the solution.

Comment: I thought I had answered your comment already, strange... I’m confused. It is quite unlikely the method you use to access the column is at fault here. I fail to see how my comment wasn’t helpful, it was just a style/design(ish) suggestion. Are you asking me to post an answer myself? You shared the solution in this very post, and have already accepted an answer, so am I missing something?